# onclick not calling JS function (on any browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
<button id="banButton{$id}"onclick="deletePhoto({$id}, {$picture_path});">BAN {$id}</button>
```

And before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../profile/theme/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function deletePhoto(id, pic_path) {
    alert("test");
    $.post("ajax.php", { toid: toid, pic_path: pic_path });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test2");

});


</script>
```

The rendered HTML could look like:

```
<button id="banButton508" onclick="deletePhoto(508, profile_photos/686733/1_4044.jpg);">BAN 508</button> <img src="../profile/pics/686725/2_3234.jpg" width="150" height="150"/>
```

The "test2" alert shows up when loading the page, but when clicking on the button, the function doesn't run (alert doesn't even show up).

Any idea why?

Edit: I've now wrapped the picture_path in quotes, like

```
<button id="banButton{$id}" class="banButton" onclick="deletePhoto({$id}, "{$picture_path}");">BAN {$id}</button>
```

still not working with this.

Comment: is there any error in the console? can you also share the generated html for the button

Comment: can you open the browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: Putting the picture path in single quote was one of the problem. The other one that I found out thanks to console that you suggested (will always use from now on...), deletePhoto was passing 'id', not 'toid'. Changed 'id' parameter to ''toid' in the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `picture_path` is a string literal, enclose it with in `''` also if the the `id` value also is a string then do the same for that also

```
<button id="banButton{$id}" onclick="deletePhoto('{$id}', '{$picture_path}');">BAN {$id}</button>
```

Comment: Thanks -- along with that I also had to change from 'id' to 'toid' in the deletePhoto function.

Comment: @DanyP yes.... it will giving a reference error since the variable was not referred

Answer (score 0):

try placing your function inside the document ready function along with everything else.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function deletePhoto(id, pic_path) {
    alert("test");
    $.post("ajax.php", { toid: toid, pic_path: pic_path });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Test</title>
  </head>

<body>

<button id="banButton508" onclick="deletePhoto(508, 'profile_photos/686733/1_4044.jpg');">BAN 508</button> <img src="../profile/pics/686725/2_3234.jpg" width="150" height="150"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function deletePhoto(id, pic_path) {
alert("test"+pic_path);
$.post("ajax.php", { toid: toid, pic_path: pic_path });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("test2");

});


</script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery then why should not manipulating dom-aciton in standard form.

like

```
<button id="banButton{id}" data-id="{id}" data-image_url="{$picture_path}">BAN {id}</button>
```

and the javascript

```
function deletePhoto(id, pic_path) {
    alert("test");
    $.post("ajax.php", { toid: toid, pic_path: pic_path });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test2");

    $("button[id^='banButton']").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var img_url = $(this).data('image_url');

        deletePhoto(id, img_url);
    });

});
```